# Live Video stops playing after 2 seconds in embedded Youtube Player in android app

Tags: android, youtube, live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api, ytplayer

Below is the  code I have used inside the activity here I have embedded the youtube player!
In a nutshell, the videoId of the Live Stream is being passed to the youtube player from a youtube Data API call.

Whenever I try to play the live stream on the embedded layer, the video pauses after 2 seconds!
I created a demo app earlier to check the feasibility of embedding the YT Player. The video is streaming without any problems in that app! I have implemented the same code here but I am facing the above mentioned issue!

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
        youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtubeView);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String showVideo = bundle.getString(ConstantsYtPlayer.VIDEO_ID);
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(showVideo);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
        if(youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()){
            youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this, "Error Initializing Youtube Player", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST){
            getYoutubePlayerProvider().initialize(API_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYoutubePlayerProvider(){
        return youTubePlayerView;}



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your logcat. You cannot have views overlapping the YouTubePlayer.